# Multi thread shell script

Tags: multithreading, bash, shell, unix

can anybody help me with writing a multi thread shell script

Basically i have two files one file contain around >10K lines(main_file) and another contain around 200 line(sub_file). These 200 lines contain repeated string sorted of main file.I'm trying make separate files for each string  to other file using below command

i have collected the string which are repeated into sub_file.
The string are present randomly in main_file.

```
a=0
while IFS= read -r line
do
a=$(($a+1));
users[$a]=$line
egrep "${line}" $main_file >> $line
done <"$sub_file"
```

if i make to use in single thread it take more time so thinking to use multithread process and complete the process in minimum time..

help me out...

Comment: It's tough to imagine `grep` taking too long with files <= 5000 lines.  Moreover, it's hard to figure what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I don't know what kind of operation you are applying to 5200 lines in a file, I can't think of any operation taking longer than a few moments. Maybe it's an option to import things into a database, let the engine do the operations and export into a file?

Comment: @devnull:the file are at an average of 5000 if i try split ,it uneditted its more then 10K lines

Comment: @DanFromGermany:200 line are repeated string of main_file,if tried to seperate will get around 300 lines matching with string in main_file

Comment: Note that [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) should be avoided. Optimize your code only when you **REALLY** need to...

Answer (score 2):

The tool you need for that is gnu `parallel`:

```
parallel egrep '{}' "$mainfile" '>' '{}' < "$sub_file"
```

You can adjust the number of jobs processed with the option `-P`:

```
parallel -P 4 egrep '{}' "$mainfile" '>' '{}' < "$sub_file"
```

Please see the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html) for more info.

By the way to make sure that you don't process a line twice you could make the input unique:

```
awk '!a[$0]++' "$sub_file" | parallel -P 4 egrep '{}' "$mainfile" '>' '{}'
```

Comment: parallel -P 4 gives an error :: parallel: invalid option -- 'P'

Comment: @suhas Try `-j` option or `--jobs` instead. Another is `--max-procs`. `-P` is actually a synonym to them. And make sure you place the option before `egrep`.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: Posting from my previous post. This is not directly applicable, but very similar to tweak

I have a file 1.txt with the below contents.

```
-----cat 1.txt-----
1234
5678
1256
1234
1247
```

---

I have 3 more files in a folder

```
-----ls -lrt-------
A1.txt
A2.txt
A3.txt
```

---

The contents of those three files are similar format with different data values (All the three files are tab delimited)

```
-----cat A1.txt----
A   X   1234    B   1234
A   X   5678    B   1234
A   X   1256    B   1256
```

---

```
-----cat A2.txt----
A   Y   8888    B   1234
A   Y   9999    B   1256
A   X   1234    B   1256
```

---

```
-----cat A3.txt----
A   Y   6798    C   1256
```

---

My objective is to do a search on all the A1,A2 and A3 (Only for the 3rd column of the TAB delimited file)for text in 1.txt 
and the output must be redirected to the file matches.txt as given below.

```
Code:
/home/A1.txt:A   X   1234    B   1234
/home/A1.txt:A   X   5678    B   1234
/home/A1.txt:A   X   1256    B   1256
/home/A2.txt:A   X   1234    B   1256
```

The following should work.

```
cat A*.txt | tr -s '\t' '|' > combined.dat

{ while read myline;do
recset=`echo $myline | cut -f19 -d '|'|tr -d '\r'`
var=$(grep $recset 1.txt|wc -l)
if [[ $var -ne 0 ]]; then
echo $myline >> final.dat 
fi
done } < combined.dat

{ while read myline;do
recset=`echo $myline | cut -f19 -d '|'|tr -d '\r'`
var=$(grep $recset 1.txt|wc -l)
if [[ $var -ne 0 ]]; then
echo $myline >> final2.dat 
fi
done } < combined.dat
```

Using AWK

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=1}$3 in a{print FILENAME":"$0}' 1.txt A* > matches.txt
```

For pipe delimited

```
awk –F’|’ 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=1}$3 in a{print FILENAME":"$0}' 1.txt A* > matches.txt
```

Comment: :By using above piece of code the system hangs,CPU utilization reaches to 99%(because regular usage of grep).the same can be achieved by using awk (in less time and CPU utilization).this was not i was looking for

Comment: @suhas Modified the answer with AWK. Not tested though